# Youtube won't update captions for a video

Tags: node.js, youtube, google-oauth, youtube-data-api, google-api-nodejs-client

am trying to insert/update captions for a video on my channel using the below code snippet,

```
let tokens = {
  access_token: 'ya29...',
  scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload',
  token_type: 'Bearer',
  id_token: 'ey....',
  expiry_date: 1672523820523,
user:{....}
}
```

```js
async function upsertCaption(token, videoId, caption) {

  oauth2Client.setCredentials(token);

  return youtube.captions
    .list({
      auth: oauth2Client,
      part: ["snippet"],
      videoId: videoId
    })
    .then(response => {
      let track_id = _.get(response.data, "items[0].id", 0);
      console.log(`track id ${track_id}`);

      if (track_id == 0) {
        console.log("inerting new caption");
        return youtube.captions
          .insert({
            auth: oauth2Client,
            part: "snippet",
            sync: false,
            requestBody: {
              snippet: {
                language: "en",
                name: "my captions",
                videoId: videoId,
                isDraft: false
              }
            },
            media: {
              mimeType: "*/*",
              body: caption
            }
          })
          .then(response => {
            console.log(response.data);
            return response;
          });
      } else {
        console.log("updating  caption");
        return youtube.captions
          .update({
            auth: oauth2Client,
            part: "snippet",
            sync: false,
            requestBody: {
              id: track_id,
              snippet: {
                language: "en",
                name: "my captions",
                videoId: videoId,
                isDraft: false
              }
            },
            media: {
              mimeType: "*/*",
              body: caption
            }
          })
          .then(response => {
            console.log(response.data);
            return response;
          });
      }
    });

}
```

the token used was requested with the these scopes

```
scopes = [
  "profile",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"
];
```

the logic works if am inserting new captions or updating them, but it doesn't work if am updating youtube's generated captions

```
code: 403,
  errors: [
    {
      message: 'The permissions associated with the request are not sufficient to update the caption track. The request might not be properly authorized.',
      domain: 'youtube.caption',
      reason: 'forbidden',
      location: 'id',
      locationType: 'parameter'
    }
  ]
```

what could be the issue ?

Comment: can I see the code you are using to authorize this?

Comment: can I see a [example]  what you have here isn't remotely going to work

Comment: @DaImTo, updated to list as much as needed

Comment: A [example] is piece of code that i could place into web storm and run with my own credentials.  What you have given here is NOT a complete example.    When asking a question relating to an error message Its very hard to help without a FULL example.

Comment: @DaImTo after couple of days of tracing, the issue doesn't seem to be with the code, it's actually working as expected, the issue arises when videos already have `generated captions` assgined, when I remove them, the code works, do you have input on this one ?

Answer (score 0):

> The permissions associated with the request are not sufficient to update the caption track. The request might not be properly authorized.

This error means exactly what it says. The access token you have for the currently authencated user does not contain the permissions needed for the [captions.update](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/captions/update) method.  This method requires that the user have consented to one of the following scopes

[image]

I have asked you twice to post a [example] as you have chosen not to and have only posted snippets of your code. I will just have to guess that you are storing the access token some place in your code.  You authorized your application and then changed the scopes in your code.  What you did not do is delete the old token and request authorization of the user again.  I cant see your code so I don't know where you are storing it.

## Check the quick start for proper authorization example

I think you should follow the official [YouTube data api quickstart for node.js](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/nodejs)

This quick start will show you how to properly authorize your application.  It even stores the user credentials in TOKEN_PATH.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var readline = require('readline');
var {google} = require('googleapis');
var OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;

// If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
// at ~/.credentials/youtube-nodejs-quickstart.json
var SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly'];
var TOKEN_DIR = (process.env.HOME || process.env.HOMEPATH ||
    process.env.USERPROFILE) + '/.credentials/';
var TOKEN_PATH = TOKEN_DIR + 'youtube-nodejs-quickstart.json';

// Load client secrets from a local file.
fs.readFile('client_secret.json', function processClientSecrets(err, content) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Error loading client secret file: ' + err);
    return;
  }
  // Authorize a client with the loaded credentials, then call the YouTube API.
  authorize(JSON.parse(content), getChannel);
});

/**
 * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
 * given callback function.
 *
 * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
 * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
 */
function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  var clientSecret = credentials.installed.client_secret;
  var clientId = credentials.installed.client_id;
  var redirectUrl = credentials.installed.redirect_uris[0];
  var oauth2Client = new OAuth2(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUrl);

  // Check if we have previously stored a token.
  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, function(err, token) {
    if (err) {
      getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback);
    } else {
      oauth2Client.credentials = JSON.parse(token);
      callback(oauth2Client);
    }
  });
}

/**
 * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
 * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
 *
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oauth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
 * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback to call with the authorized
 *     client.
 */
function getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback) {
  var authUrl = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: SCOPES
  });
  console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url: ', authUrl);
  var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
  });
  rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', function(code) {
    rl.close();
    oauth2Client.getToken(code, function(err, token) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Error while trying to retrieve access token', err);
        return;
      }
      oauth2Client.credentials = token;
      storeToken(token);
      callback(oauth2Client);
    });
  });
}

/**
 * Store token to disk be used in later program executions.
 *
 * @param {Object} token The token to store to disk.
 */
function storeToken(token) {
  try {
    fs.mkdirSync(TOKEN_DIR);
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.code != 'EEXIST') {
      throw err;
    }
  }
  fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Token stored to ' + TOKEN_PATH);
  });
}

/**
 * Lists the names and IDs of up to 10 files.
 *
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
 */
function getChannel(auth) {
  var service = google.youtube('v3');
  service.channels.list({
    auth: auth,
    part: 'snippet,contentDetails,statistics',
    forUsername: 'GoogleDevelopers'
  }, function(err, response) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
      return;
    }
    var channels = response.data.items;
    if (channels.length == 0) {
      console.log('No channel found.');
    } else {
      console.log('This channel\'s ID is %s. Its title is \'%s\', and ' +
                  'it has %s views.',
                  channels[0].id,
                  channels[0].snippet.title,
                  channels[0].statistics.viewCount);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I've tried that, it's not working, to be specific ... it works if am uploading a caption for the first time, it doesn't work if am updating the youtube's `generated` caption

Comment: You can't change the generated caption you can only make q new one

Comment: how do I know if it was generated or user's caption ?

Comment: please update the answer to include information about not updating generated, as this was the root cause for the issue